# nested for loops to do a check of the elements of a python list

Tags: python, list

I need to insert within two new lists, objects that are not present in list 'PListaServiceID' but are present in list 'SListaServiceID', the same but in reverse. so I started by doing this

```
PListaServiceName = []
PListaServiceID = []
SListaServiceName = []
SListaServiceID = []
CListaServiceID = []
C2ListaServiceID = []
for i in jsonPResponse["result"][0]["data"]:
    x = i['dimensionMap']
    PListaServiceName.append(x['dt.entity.service.name'])
    PListaServiceID.append(x['dt.entity.service'])

for p in jsonSResponse["result"][0]["data"]:
    z = p['dimensionMap']
    SListaServiceName.append(z['dt.entity.service.name'])
    SListaServiceID.append(z['dt.entity.service'])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("tabella.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
#print("debug: ",NomePrimoMese)
CreateExcel(PListaServiceName,PListaServiceID, NomePrimoMese, writer)
CreateExcel(SListaServiceName,SListaServiceID, NomeSecondoMese, writer)
for c in PListaServiceID:
    for z in SListaServiceID:
        if c!=z:
            CListaServiceID.append(c)


CreateExcel(CListaServiceID, SListaServiceID, "Confronto", writer)
writer.close()
```

since I would have to repeat the last for loop also to fill the other new list, can there be a better way to do all this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a difference, it depends on how you want the final data, in my case I wanted a list with all the repetitions within the list. either way works

```
#Elements present in PListaServiceID but not in SListaServiceID
#without repetition
CListaServiceID = list(set(PListaServiceName) - set(SListaServiceName)) 
#with repetition
ConfrontoListaService = [ x for x in PListaServiceName if x not in SListaServiceName]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using Python's `set` operations. Here's an example:

```
PListaServiceName = []
PListaServiceID = []
SListaServiceName = []
SListaServiceID = []

for i in jsonPResponse["result"][0]["data"]:
    x = i['dimensionMap']
    PListaServiceName.append(x['dt.entity.service.name'])
    PListaServiceID.append(x['dt.entity.service'])

for p in jsonSResponse["result"][0]["data"]:
    z = p['dimensionMap']
    SListaServiceName.append(z['dt.entity.service.name'])
    SListaServiceID.append(z['dt.entity.service'])

# Find elements in PListaServiceID but not in SListaServiceID
CListaServiceID = list(set(PListaServiceID) - set(SListaServiceID))

# Find elements in SListaServiceID but not in PListaServiceID
C2ListaServiceID = list(set(SListaServiceID) - set(PListaServiceID))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("tabella.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
CreateExcel(PListaServiceName, PListaServiceID, NomePrimoMese, writer)
CreateExcel(SListaServiceName, SListaServiceID, NomeSecondoMese, writer)
CreateExcel(CListaServiceID, SListaServiceID, "Confronto", writer)
CreateExcel(C2ListaServiceID, PListaServiceID, "ConfrontoReverse", writer)
writer.close()
```

Comment: perfect was what I needed